# Angularjs tutorial based on real time project

Tags: angularjs

I know the basic about angularjs, Which site is best suitable for me that tell me about angular real time problem based project with example step by step

Comment: Unfortunately this type of questions is off-topic here and elsewhere on SE.

Answer (score 1):

codeschool.com is my personal favourite. They have videos and step by step questions/answers.

egghead.io is okay.. I don't recommend it for beginners because there isn't really a structured course with egghead.io - however, this may be useful for you if you know how angular works but want a deeper understanding of the individual components.